# Cannot add an Run On Demand WebJob to an Azure Mobile App

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-webjobs

In the Azure Mobile App documentation there is a section explaining how to add a "Run One Demand" Webjob, however when I try to add one, I have available only the options for Continuous and Scheduled.

This is the documentation I am referring to: [Run Background tasks with WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)

I am in a subscription within the free price tier.

Any suggestions on how to add a "Run On Demand" Webjob?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easier than I thought. The documentation is out of date.
I needed to define the webjob as triggered and then there is a second option that changes from scheduled to Webhook. Then the webhook can be called on demand.